# How to interrupt sympy calculations?

Tags: sympy, interrupt, calculation

I use *sympy* library in my project.
I need to interrupt the calculations taking a long time, how can i do it in *sympy*?
I'm thinking about using a parallel thread for calculations and killing it after required amount of time, but may be there is another way?

Comment: This is not really a sympy specific question. The answer you want is probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Comment: Sympy has no it's own mechanism to stop calculations? I can only stop the calculations by specific language features, right?